# How do i completely logout of Google Cloud? `gcloud auth revoke --all` doesn't cut it

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Logging out of Google Cloud *seems* like it should be easy. If I run:

```
$ unset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

$ gcloud auth revoke --all
Revoked credentials:
  - [my account]
$ gcloud auth list

No credentialed accounts.

To login, run:
  $ gcloud auth login `ACCOUNT`
```

It at first *looks* like I'm completely logged out of `gcloud`. But watch what happens when I open a Python shell:

```
>>> from google.cloud import secretmanager_v1beta1 as secretmanager
>>> client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
/Users/my/path/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:66: UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
  warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)
>>> path = client.secret_version_path(project="my-project-name", secret="my-secret", secret_version="latest")
>>> secret = client.access_secret_version(path)
>>> secret.payload.data.decode()
"Oh, no! I should be secret!"
```

As you can see, even though I ran `gcloud auth revoke --all` I'm still able to access Google Cloud through the Python SDK using user credentials that are stored somewhere. Is there a way to *completely* logout of Google Cloud on my laptop?

EDIT: to clarify further: there aren't any Google Cloud Service account JSON files saved on this computer, and I've unset the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

Comment: I would like to know from where are you revoking access to your accounts. Is it from Google Cloud Shell? Or perhaps from your local machine? Thank you.

Comment: @ChristopherRodriguezConde all the commands here are running locally on my MacBook (good ol' zsh in iTerm).

Comment: I see no relation between the Client Libraries and the fact you revoke access using the `gcloud` command. `gcloud revoke --all` will sign out you to use any `gcloud` command if I am not mistaken, while for 'logging out' in the sense you would like to control access to the Client Libraries use service accounts, and assign those service accounts to your end-users, but I think there's no relation between revoking access and actually running the Python's Client Libraries. I hope it helps.

Comment: @ChristopherRodriguezConde but there _is_ a relationship because if these isn't a service account it will default to using the `gcloud` authorization credentials. My goal is to be completely logged out such that the SDK is unable to authenticate, which includes not having any service account files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you in any way but I ran into a similar issue. Once I had revoked all credentials using the command `gcloud auth revoke --all` I still was able the execute scripts against my environment.  In the end, I found the application default credentials file locating in **~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json**. Renaming or deleting this file helped to revoke credentials completely. And now client library has no access to the environment:

```
  File "audit_test.py", line 8, in main
    client = resource_manager.Client()
  File "fake_path/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/resource_manager/client.py", line 72, in __init__
    super(Client, self).__init__(credentials=credentials, _http=_http)
  File "fake_path/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 132, in __init__
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
  File "fake_path/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 321, in default
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

Comment: There is a command `gcloud auth application-default revoke` which revokes the credentials in that file (and all copies of that file)

Comment: Deleting `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` is the fool-proof way to get rid of it. Executing `gcloud auth application-default revoke` doesn't necessarily cut it if that credential is invalid (maybe expired, etc.) for some reason and `gcloud` prints out `ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.revoke) ('invalid_token', None)`. In such a case, the Python call `google.auth.default()` still succeeds and returns a non-empty `credentials` object -- not your desired outcome. Only by deleting that file will the Python call throws an `Exception` which is the desired outcome.

Answer (score -1):

As commented above by [AjahnCharles](https://serverfault.com/users/512040/ajahncharles), `gcloud auth application-default revoke` works. Just hit the command and it will remove the `application-default` creds. See the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306131/difference-between-gcloud-auth-application-default-login-and-gcloud-auth-logi). I had the same problem and only this worked.

**Edit:**

Remember that you still need to call `gcloud auth revoke --all` as `gcloud auth application-default revoke` only removes the application-default creds.